# How can I get CVtypes for OpenCV working in Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, opencv

I have downloaded [CVtypes](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~gb/blog/2007/02/04/python-opencv-wrapper-using-ctypes/) and tried the example scripts with it but cannot get it working. The error I get is:

```
pete@pete-MacBookPro:~/python_scratch/cvtypes$ python showcam.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "showcam.py", line 1, in <module>
    from CVtypes import cv
  File "/home/pete/python_scratch/cvtypes/CVtypes.py", line 580, in <module>
    _cxDLL = cdll.cxcore100
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 423, in __getattr__
    dll = self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: cxcore100: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have installed all these packages for good measure which I thought would contain the required libs:

```
libcv-dev - development files for libcv
libcv2.1 - computer vision library
libcvaux-dev - development files for libcvaux
libcvaux2.1 - computer vision extension library
libhighgui-dev - development files for libhighgui
libhighgui2.1 - computer vision GUI library
opencv-doc - OpenCV documentation and examples
python-opencv - Python bindings for the computer vision library
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out CVtypes is ooooold. I needed [PyOpenCV](http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/) instead. As a Perl coder who is a newbie to Python I find the instability and deprecation a bit annoying.